# What does it mean - login via SSL

Tags: iphone, ssl

I have to implement login in iPhone application via SSL. What does it mean? Can anybody provide me some tutorial on how to this on iPhone? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secure Sockets Layer, predecessor of Transport Layer Security, a communications protocol
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer